# Geometrical proof of the impossibility of angle trisection by straightedge and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, arithmetic-geometry

There's a fascinating (almost) [geometrical proof of the impossibility of angle trisection by straightedge and compass](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/a-geometric-proof-of-the-impossibility-of-angle-trisection-by-straightedge-and-compass/) by Terrence Tao which is somehow more comprehensible (and more directly to the point) than [Wantzel's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Proof_of_impossibility).

I wonder if Tao was the first to take this endeavour or if there were earlier attempts (which possibly got stuck)?